# Indefinite multiple integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

Let:

$\displaystyle F(x,y) = \int \int \frac{1}{xy} \, dx \, dy$

be a bidimensional indefinite integral. I would like to understand the correct way to handle it.

My first attempt would be to simply solve the integral inside in $dx$ and then the outer one in $dy$.

That is:

$\displaystyle F(x,y) = \int \frac{\log x}{y} + c_1 \, dy = \log(x) \log(y) + y \, c_1 + c_2$

In this way however I get a non symmetric result, starting from a symmetric argument.

The second attempt would be:

$\displaystyle F(x,y) = \int \frac{\log x + c_1}{y} \, dy = (\log x + c_1)(\log y + c_2)$

In this way I get a symmetric result. However I'm not sure it's correct to divide $c_1$ by $y$. In a way, $y$ is a constant if seen from the inside integral. However if I consider it constant, then why $y$ and not $y^2$.

Technically both solutions, if derived respect to $x$ and $y$ give the same starting argument.

Can you explain which one is correct (if one is) and why?

Comment: An indefinite integral (and really antiderivatives) are only a well defined concept in 1D, at least in this context.

Comment: @NinadMunshi is right. But let's *assume* that we can. Then the second one would theoretically be the right result.

Comment: @vitamind I get where you're coming from, but our bounds are not always rectangular. You can't get behind that interpretation either, since it respects Fubini factoring when we don't know if the integral can factor.

Comment: @NinadMunshi No,no. I'm aware of that. I was actually adressing the OP. Just wanted to say that the first solution doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Also don't forget that when you take a “partial” antiderivative with respect to some variable, the “constant” of integration will in fact be a function of all the *other* variables.

Comment: $c y+d+f(y)+\log x \log y$ where $f(y)$ is an arbitrary function

Comment: ok, but does the order matters or not when integrating 1/(xy)?